# Update statement is no query?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

How do I define the update statement in the orm.xml. I have it as a named-query and everything works, but my teacher said that an update statement isn't a query. I have tried a native query, but that wasn't working.

ORM-Type:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd">
```

Update Statement:

```xml
<named-query name="updateTshirts">
    <query>
        update Tshirt tshirt Set tshirt.bEdit = :bedit, tshirt.farbe = :farbe,
        tshirt.groesse = :groesse, tshirt.markenName = :markenname where
        tshirt.tID = :tid
    </query>
</named-query>
```

Comment: Which ORM is this? It looks like JPA XML, so probably Hibernate?

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i am new to this. I have edited the Question :) Thank you for your patience^^

Comment: In any case, it sounds like your teacher is hung-up on the semantics of the word query, which some interpret as "something that produce a result set" (your teacher), while others interpret it broader as "any DML statement" (the JPA specification in this case). In short, your current definition seems to be correct. The difference between `named-query` is that it accepts JPQL, while `named-native-query` accepts SQL in the native dialect of your target database system.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Alright Thank you Sir :) Then i ll not modify anything. Have a nice Day ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term *"query"* is used rather ambiguously. Some people interpret it literally as "asking for information", meaning only select statements or other things producing a result set fall under this term, while others interpret it more broadly as any DML (Data Manipulation Language, i.e. select, insert, update, delete, merge, etc) statement.

Your teacher seems to fall in the first category, while the people who created the Jakarta Persistence API (JPA) fall into the second category. So, in a sense you're both right, in the first interpretation, an update statement is not a "query", but in the second interpretation, which is used by JPA, it is a "query".

However, given the context, your interpretation is the better one.